# Mongo count number of objects grouped by a field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following mongo model:

```
{
    "_id" : "5f5a1c1f6976570001783ab7",
    "date" : NumberLong(1590624000),
    "source" : "here",
}
```

I would like to have the number of documents, group by date, that have source field at here value for example:

```
{
    "date" : NumberLong(1590624000),
    "count": 5
},

{
    "date" : NumberLong(1590710400),
    "count": 10
}
```

What mongo query should I use to have the following result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [$match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/https://) to filter the records you want then use [$group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to group by date

test it here: [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xR57s_Bx-3w)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "source": "here"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$date",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "date": "$_id",
      "count": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and what if i want the results to be returned with an ascending date?

Comment: Just adding an other stage with `{$sort: {date:1}}`

Answer (score 1):

you can use aggregation query for it.

```
db.getCollection('dailyRoutes').aggregate([{$match:{source:'here'}},{$addFields:{count:1}},{$group:{_id:'$date', totalDocuments:{$sum:"$count"}}}])
```